# Memory size of the SVN repository while doing a branch/tag

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Let's assume Trunk folder has 1MB size. I have 2 things to know about memory size.

1. if Trunk folder is branched for parallel development, whether the Branch will occupy additional 1MB size? since we do a SVN copy for branching, will it increase the repository size?
2. if Trunk folder is tagged as it's released, whether the tag folder will occupy additional 1MB size? since tag will copy the trunk folder, will it increase the repository size?

at the end, how the SVN repository size will be impacted by branching & tagging the trunk folder.

Answer (score 2):

I will quote here the subversion mantra from the svn redbook.

> branches and tags are cheap. So don't be afraid to use them when
> needed!

When a directory is copied in subversion into branches or tags the size of repository doesn't grow. When we create branch or a tag from trunk the subversion doesn't actually duplicate the data. *It creates a new directory entry that points to an existing tree*. Subversion applies this concept wherever possible.

So size is not impacted by branching and tagging the trunk folder.